# Почему не перезаписывается стейт в setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Почему не работает функция mathArmy, которая должна обновлять стейт recruting

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react'
import question from '../../../assets/svg/question.svg';
import archerImg from '../../../assets/png/archeryArmy.png';
import './Recruting.scss'

export default function Recruting() {
  const [recruting, setRecruting] = useState({
    archers: 0,
    infantry: 0,
    horsemen: 0,
    archersGarnizon: 0,
    infantryGarnizon: 0,
    horsemenGarnizon: 0,
    archersCooldown: 2,
    archersStart: '',
    archersCurrentTime: '',
    archersTimeRecruting: '',
    archersEnd: '',
  })
  const [proccessBar, setProccessBar] = useState({
    archers: 0,
    infantry: 0,
    horsemen: 0,
  })

  const intervalRef = useRef(null)

  const timerCalculate = (digit) => {
    let hours = Math.floor(digit / 3600 % 24);
    let minutes = Math.floor(digit / 60 % 60);
    let seconds = Math.floor(digit % 60);
    return `${hours > 0 ? `${hours}часов,` : ''} ${minutes > 0 ? `${minutes}минут,` : ''} ${seconds > 0 ? `${seconds}секунд ` : ''}`
  }

  const onChangeRecruting = (value, name) => {
    setRecruting({ ...recruting, [name]: value })
  }

  const handleStartRecruting = (name, timeCooldownSec, count) => {
    const timeStart = Date.now()
    const timeRecruting = timeCooldownSec * count
    const timeEnd = timeStart + timeRecruting
    setRecruting({ ...recruting, [name + `Start`]: timeStart, [name + `End`]: timeEnd, [name + `TimeRecruting`]: timeRecruting, [name + `CurrentTime`]: timeStart })

  }

  const mathProccesBar = useCallback(() => {
    const totalTime = recruting.archersTimeRecruting
    const currentTime = parseInt(((Date.now() - recruting.archersStart) / 1000).toFixed())
    const proccessBarValue = currentTime / totalTime * 100
    setProccessBar({ ...proccessBar, archers: proccessBarValue })
    mathArmy()
    if (proccessBarValue >= 100) {
      setRecruting({ ...recruting, archersTimeRecruting: '' })
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
    }

  },[recruting])


  const mathArmy = useCallback(() => {
    const timePlusCooldown = Date.now() + recruting.archersCooldown
    const currentTimeArchersPlusCd = recruting.archersCurrentTime + recruting.archersCooldown
    const currentTimeCd = parseInt(((timePlusCooldown - currentTimeArchersPlusCd) / 1000).toFixed())
    if (currentTimeCd >= recruting.archersCooldown) {
      // setRecruting({...recruting, archersGarnizon: recruting.archersGarnizon + 1, archersCurrentTime: Date.now()})
      setRecruting((prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          archersGarnizon: prev.archersGarnizon + 1,
          archersCurrentTime: Date.now()
        }
      });
      
    }
    console.log(recruting.archersGarnizon)
  },[recruting])



  useEffect(() => {
    if (recruting.archersTimeRecruting) {
      intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => mathProccesBar(), 1000)
    }
  }, [recruting.archersTimeRecruting])

  return (
    <div className="recruting">
      <div className="recruting__item">
        <img src={archerImg} alt="archercs" />
        <div className='recruting__container'>
          <span>{recruting.archersGarnizon}</span>
          <button type='button' className='recruting__btnTake'>Взять в армию</button>
        </div>
        <div className='recruting__container'>
          <span>Найм лучников</span>
          {recruting.archersTimeRecruting ?
            <>
              <div className="recruting__proccessBar">
                <div className="recruting__barItem" style={{ width: proccessBar.archers + '%' }}></div>
              </div>
              <div className='recruting__timer'>
                {timerCalculate(recruting.archersTimeRecruting)}
              </div>
            </>
            :
            <>
              <span className='recruting__counter'>{recruting.archers}</span>
              <input className='recruting__input' type="range" value={recruting.archers} onChange={(e) => onChangeRecruting(e.target.value, 'archers')} />
            </>
          }

        </div>
        <div className="recruting__container">
          <span className='recruting__cooldown'>{recruting.archersCooldown} секунд</span>
          <button type='button' className='recruting__btnRecrut' onClick={() => handleStartRecruting('archers', recruting.archersCooldown, recruting.archers)}>Нанять</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="recruting__item">
        <img src={archerImg} alt="archercs" />
        <div className='recruting__container'>
          <span>30</span>
          <button type='button' className='recruting__btnTake'>Взять в армию</button>
        </div>
        <div className='recruting__container'>
          <span>Найм лучников</span>
          <span className='recruting__counter'>{recruting.infantry}</span>
          <input className='recruting__input' type="range" value={recruting.infantry} onChange={(e) => onChangeRecruting(e.target.value, 'infantry')} />
        </div>
        <div className="recruting__container">
          <span className='recruting__cooldown'>5 мин</span>
          <button type='button' className='recruting__btnRecrut'>Нанять</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="recruting__item">
        <img src={archerImg} alt="archercs" />
        <div className='recruting__container'>
          <span>30</span>
          <button type='button' className='recruting__btnTake'>Взять в армию</button>
        </div>
        <div className='recruting__container'>
          <span>Найм лучников</span>
          <span className='recruting__counter'>{recruting.horsemen}</span>
          <input className='recruting__input' type="range" value={recruting.horsemen} onChange={(e) => onChangeRecruting(e.target.horsemen, 'horsemen')} />
        </div>
        <div className="recruting__container">
          <span className='recruting__cooldown'>5 мин</span>
          <button type='button' className='recruting__btnRecrut'>Нанять</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` работает асинхронно

> Вызовы setState являются асинхронными, поэтому не стоит рассчитывать, что this.state отобразит новое значение мгновенно после вызова setState.

https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value

Поэтому `console.log` сразу после `setRecruting` не будет показывать новое значение.